# Implementation of square root method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

My partner and I are working on a deterministic physics engine that will run exactly the same on various platforms. In order to make such a thing, we are using either fixed point or truncated floating point math (we'll figure it out later). However, in order for the engine to be ported to Javascript, we have to make sure that the double precision floating point operations in Javascript that we will use are consistent with whatever operations we will be using in the desktop port.

With that in mind, my question is: How is Math.sqrt() implemented in Javascript? If there are different implementations across browsers, what are those implementations? Or, if there is no certain answer for the previous questions, what is the maximum amount of error that Math.sqrt() can produce?

We prefer not to write our own square root function since the natively implemented Math.sqrt() will always outperform whatever we write in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (the ECMAScript 5.1 specification) does not require a specific implementation for `Math.sqrt` and only requires specific results for unusual number values (`NaN`, `-0`, etc):

> 15.8.2.17 sqrt (x)
>
> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the square root of x.
>
> - If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - If x is less than 0, the result is NaN.
> - If x is +0, the result is +0.
> - If x is -0, the result is -0.
> - If x is +Infinity, the result is +Infinity.